# Using a link to call a javascript function that inserts a file into a div

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, load, external

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function link(page){
   function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#content').load(page);
   }
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="link(gg.htm)">Link</a>

<div id="content"></div>
```

I'm pretty stuck on this one - can anyone point to the problem? Nothing happens when I click the link :(

Answer (score 2):

Change `link(gg.htm)` by `link('gg.htm')`

and

```
function link(page){
   function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#content').load(page);
   }
}
```

by

```
function link(page){
    window.event.preventDefault();
    $('#content').load(page);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using jQuery, so why not use their events? I'd probably do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".load_link").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#content").load($(this).data("link"));
    });
});
</script>

<a href="#" data-link="gg.htm" class="load_link">Link</a>

<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: OP: you probably want something more specific than `$("a")` though.